# Sub-domain for azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, subdomain, domain-name, ns-record

I have a A record pointing to Azure website IP address.

Now I want to direct a subdomain to a Azure virtual machine.

Can I create a NS record `xxx.example.com -> xxx.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com`?

Do I need to create any CNAME records?

Do I have to do any domain verification at Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to direct a particular sub domain to a VM then you don't need an NS record, an NS record is for where you want to delegate responsibility for a subdomain to that VM, so you want it to act as a DNS server for that subdomain. If you do want to do that  you need to re-word your question.

If your just looking to direct traffic for that URL to the VM in question then you need to create a CNAME to point to the name of the machine or cloud service, or an A record to point to it's IP. If you are usign dynamic IP's then you are best using a CNAME to account for the IP changing.

Note that if you have CNAME pointing to a cloud service (if you are using V1 VMs) then that is pointing to a the cloud service, not the VM and could be used to access any end point in the cloud service.